# What does the lady say at the begining of this video?

Tags: pronunciation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSZ_t35cTKI

What does the lady say in this videos? first 10 seconds

Comment: Sorry, this isn't the place to get video transcriptions. If you have a particular problem with one of the sentences, I would suggest that you ask about that.

Comment: Can't make out a single word except that she's not happy with some of her 'friends'.

Comment: It was intentionally garbled.

Comment: Turn on 'subtitles'

Comment: Is she not doing Stanley Baxter or Dame Edna? A spoof of a spoof?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  this isn't the place to get video transcriptions.

Comment: @Hot Licks: Intentionally garbled? Painstakingly precise diction was a trademark feature of Hyacinth Bucket!

Answer (score 1):

[Hyacinth Bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyacinth_Bucket) says

> I'm having the W.I. [[Women's Institute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women%27s_Institute)] round for a
> soirée. Tricia Simpson's been acting like [Egon Ronay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egon_Ronay) since she got a fondue set.

Comment: The famous TV character  used to pepper her speech with "posh" French words to sound upper crust

Comment: @Mari-LouA notably her own name, which she pronounced as [*Bouquet*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=bouquet)